# Can a Vue application have a competitive SEO?

Tags: seo, google, single-page-application

Supose you have a Vue application, that fetches and alters data through a REST server. So, on one hand, you have a Vue single-page app, and on the other, a server responding to an HTTP REST interface.

I do not expect the Vue application to be crawled for the contents, for the data served by the REST. But I do expect to know if I can have a good SEO to reach high places by keywords refering to the general topic of the application, just with the SEO that is attachable to a Vue application.

Thank you.

Comment: I've never used Vue so I'm not sure exactly how it works.  Is it truly a "single page" such that the URL never changes even as you use the site, or does it use `pushState` to change the URL you navigate?   What type of elements does it use for navigation?  Does it create `<a>` nodes in the DOM with `href` attributes?

Answer (score 1):

I would say: yes, it can become SEO conform. But to do so, your working effort will be much, **MUCH**, higher, than a page, which is done using basic paradigm of the internet.

This paradigm is URI/URL - unique ressource identifier/locator. Javascript frameworks don't use this paradigm, so to SEO your pages, you will be forced to create and maintain URIs/URLs.